# C - ftell() function

Tags: c, pointers

I don't understand why i get this strange result by this function with some files.

For example if i have a

> input.txt

and inside of it there is a string like

> abcd

if i do something like:

```
FILE* file = fopen("intput.txt", "r");
char currentChar;
long n = ftell(file); //return 0 it's ok
fread(&currentChar, sizeof(char), 1, file);
long n = ftell(file); // return 1 it's ok
```

Now if i do the same things but with a (for example) .png file i have different result:

```
FILE* file = fopen("intput.png", "r");
char currentChar;
long n = ftell(file); //return 0 it's ok
fread(&currentChar, sizeof(char), 1, file);
long n = ftell(file); // return 216 why return 216 and not 1
```

I don't understand why with the input.png file i get 216 instead of 1

Comment: did you check fread result ?

Comment: try `FILE* file = fopen("intput.png", "rb");` and also `long n` redefinition.

Comment: yes in both files it get the first byte

Comment: Are you on windows? or unix?

Comment: im on windows, with the binary reading mode it works, thx

Comment: Are you sure that another file exists?

Comment: .png files purposely have a leading 8-byte header designed to catch text-mode file processing.   [Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)